# Python sum string (?)

Tags: python, arrays, sum

I receive from a server this answer
`a =b'[10,20]'`

1. How to sum values?
2. If I use `sum(a)` I get 423. Why?

Comment: A `bytes` value is basically a sequence of integers between 0 and 255; you are summing those integers.

Comment: `import ast; a_new = ast.literal_eval(a.decode('UTF-8'))`

Comment: What's the actual format used by the server? JSON? Python notation? Something else? Are the numbers always "integers", or can there be other kind of values like floating point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b'[10,20]'` is a `bytes` object. Unlike an `str` (unicode in Python 2), it expands into a list of integers 0..255:

```
>>> list(b'[10,20]')
[91, 49, 48, 44, 50, 48, 93]
```

Perhaps what you want to do is to parse the json and then get a sum of the resulting list:

```
>>> import json
>>> sum(json.loads(b'[10,20]'))
30
```

Answer (score 0):

A `bytes` value is a sequence of integers; for display purposes, ASCII characters are used where possible.

```
>>> list(b'[10,20]')
[91, 49, 48, 44, 50, 48, 93]
>>> sum(_)
423
```

You want to decode the `bytes` value to a `str`, then parse that as a list of `int` values.

```
>>> import ast
>>> sum(ast.literal_eval(b'[10,20]'.decode()))
30
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum the list `a` you can use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) package for python and just convert to a list.

There are some simple ways to accomplish that:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(a)
[10,20]
>>> sum(json.loads(a))
30
```

The sum results in 423 because `a` it's a `bytes` object, a sequence of ints that gives an ascii-rapresentation when displayed using `repr()` or `str()`

take a look at this:

```
>>> a = b'[1,2,3]'
>>> list(a)
[91, 49, 44, 50, 44, 51, 93]
```

As you can see it's a sequence of integers and not a sequence of characters, like a string.